# How to get the Packages I am Using in Jupyter into PyCharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

I have recently started using PyCharm to write my python code. In the past, I have used Jupyter Notebook more.

I thought that the packages I have installed in Jupyter would work in PyCharm, but this is not the case. I keep getting "module not found" errors in Pycharm.

How do I configure Pycharm so that all the packages I have installed in Jupyter are usable PyCharm as well? The only way I can think of is to reinstall each module separately in Pycharm, but there are so many that I have installed in Jupyter that it would not be practical.

Comment: If you used a virtual environment for your jupyter, then you can reuse it in your PyCharm project: Under `file -> settings -> <project> -> Python interpreter` you can select an existing virtual environment to be used as the project's one.

Comment: How would I get Jupyter to tell me what the file path to the virtual environment is? Is there some sort of print statement? I ask because when I tried checking the interpreter, I see multiple different versions of Python. I don't know which one I have all my packages downloaded to.

Comment: I think it depends which Python distribution you are using. Here is a tutorial for various possibilities: <https://janakiev.com/blog/jupyter-virtual-envs/>. If you are on the command line and inside the venv, the command to list the venv would be `jupyter kernelspec list`. Note that the venv is just a folder with a python executable and the downloaded packages.

Comment: Hey, as an update to this, I was able to find the virtual environment.

Comment: I can now use the packages.

Comment: Simple: InPycharm  file -> settings -> <project> -> Python interpreter add a new interpreter and choose the python executable inside the venv. Then, all packages inside that venv are added to your projekt automatically.